# Can't find new version of ReportDocument class in Crystal Reports 2011

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I've been given the task of converting a VB6 application to DotNet. This app basically loads several crystal reports v8.5 (.rpt) files using the Report object (class) located in the Crystal Reports ActiveX Runtime Library which the application references. The app loops through the .rpt reports, loads them in memory, change the datasource, and exports them as PDF files into another file folder, weekly.

Now we need to convert this application to C# and use Crystal Reports 2011 (v14.0). I managed to convert the definition files (.rpt) to the new version format. But when I try to write C# code to load the reports, change the datasource, and export them as PDF files, I'm learning that in order to use the ReportDocument class, I still need to reference the old CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.dll.

But this DLL does not come with the new version of Crystal Reports (2011). I had to dig this file up from previous installations. I'm wondering if the ReportDocument class is in another newer DLL file that I need to reference in my C# application.

Answer (score 0):

First off, when you install Crystal Reports on your computer AFTER installing Visual Studio, it will recognize that you have VS.NET installed and install the appropriate developer DLLs that go with it. If this didn't happen, try reinstalling.

Second, you can install a developer version of CR, but it is not as complete as the version that comes with CR 2011 stand alone. But it is CR 2011 compatible and will work with VS.NET without having to install CR 2011 on your computer. Here is a link:

https://www.sap.com/campaign/ne/free_trial/crystal_reports_visual_studio/index.epx?url_id=reg-us-crvs&kNtBzmUK9zU=1

Here is another link that explains this in more detail than I did. Click on the grid cell that is appropriate for your project.
http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-25513